# How to add blocks of text with punctuations in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, bigdata

I am using java to execute postgresql statements. In one step, I need to create a table in which one column will store blocks of text (that may contain punctuation marks, such as comma, semi-colon, etc).

What data type do I use to populate this column?

For example, in the given example, I am creating a table called "MYTHOUGHTS", and that has a column called "THOUGHTS". I am trying the following code:

```
try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Opened Database Successfully");
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE MYTHOUGHTS " + "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + " THOUGHTS TEXT NOT NULL," + " Number INT NOT NULL," + " ADDRESS CHAR(50), " + " SALARY REAL)";

        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,THOUGHTS,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) " + "VALUES (1," + "This is life, as I see it. Do you think otherwise?" + ", 32, 'California', 20000.00 );";
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I get the following error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "life"
  Position: 68
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:331)
    at com.vivek.PostgreSQLExample.main(PostgreSQLExample.java:39)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "life"
  Position: 68

It is possible that TEXT data type is not appropriate. Please, let me know how I may add multiple lines of text that may have commas and periods into a column.

Thank you for your time and assistance. Highly appreciate it.

Comment: I have no idea what a "blurb of text" is supposed to be, but for character data, use the `text` datatype (or `varchar`).

Comment: My apologies. I should have been more clear. What I meant was a "paragraph of text" that may contain commas and other special characters. I tried using text datatype, but when I set values as a String in java to form the sql statement, it gives me an error due to commas in the text. Because of the commas in the text, postgresql reads it as more parameters being passed rather than it being one large String. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: My guess is that you're not using prepared statements. You should. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. If you're already using prepared statements, then show your code. The data type is not the problem. Your code is.

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/41022/1 You need to show us some code that fails or otherwise state your problem.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet. Using Prepared Statements worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `text` data type. The contents do not matter, the only thing you can't put in `text` is the null byte `\0`.

If you're having problems with the contents then you're running dangerous code that's doing direct string interpolation, instead of using parameterized statements. See: http://bobby-tables.com/ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/